One session is already running in browser in new table login same user and log out old one and continue with new one possible or not
@Component
public class CustomSessionAuthenticationStrategy implements SessionAuthenticationStrategy {
private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;
private AdminUserRepository userRepository;
public void setSessionRegistry(SessionRegistry sessionRegistry) {
    this.sessionRegistry = sessionRegistry;
}

@Autowired
public void UserServiceImpl(AdminUserRepository userRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
}

@Resource(name = "uniqueIdSessionMap")
ConcurrentHashMap<String, HttpSession> uniqueIdSessionMap;

@Override
public void onAuthentication(Authentication authentication, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws SessionAuthenticationException {
    if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetails) {
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();

        AdminUser user = userRepository.findByUserid(userDetails.getUsername());
        HttpSession currentSession = request.getSession(false);
        String uniqueId = user.getUniqueId().toString();
        if (uniqueIdSessionMap.containsKey(uniqueId)) {
            HttpSession oldsessionid = uniqueIdSessionMap.get(uniqueId);
            if (oldsessionid != null) {
                uniqueIdSessionMap.remove(uniqueId, oldsessionid);
                try {
                    oldsessionid.invalidate();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    
                }
            }
        }

        if (currentSession != null) {
            uniqueIdSessionMap.put(uniqueId, currentSession);
        }

    }

}

}
This is working fine in different browser but when same browser with new tab not working

Limiting sessions by adding maximum sessions value to 1 and session registry to Security Configuration
http.sessionManagement()
.maximumSessions(1)
.sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
.expiredUrl("/login?expired");


i tried but it's not working
